# How to Import a Gradle Jar Into Another Gradle Project

Tags: java, file, netbeans, jar, gradle

If I have a Gradle project in Netbeans, how can I get `jar`s from other local projects imported into the build file without copying the jars into a library folder? I keep having problems with this approach most notably that I have to make a small tweak with one of the other projects and then copy the `jar` from the `dist` folder to the Gradle project library folder every time a tweak occurrs.

Comment: You can publish the other projects to your local Maven repository, and then refer to them using normal dependency coordinates (group:name:version)

Comment: If the other projects are Gradle projects as well, you can also create a multi-project and let them depend on each other